# Unable to draw text onto map as overlay

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I'm trying to add text labels next to my overlay images. So far the only way I can see to do this would be to use the draw method and draw the text as overlay. I did this, but somehow it isn't showing me the drawn text. My code looks like:

```
 SitesOverlay that extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,boolean shadow) {  
    int i;  
    Paint paint=new Paint();  
    paint.setStrokeWidth(1);  
    paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);  
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);  
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);  
    boundCenterBottom(station);  
    canvas.drawText("hullo",28632877,77219722, paint);  
    }
```

My constructor in the SitesOverlay class just adds the images to many different GeoPoints.
Now, in my OnCreate I have this piece of code:

```
 map.getOverlays().add(new SitesOverlay(station));
```

This is adding the list of images in my constructor - SitesOverlay(station) as overlays.
My question is that since I have added my text in the Draw method of the SitesOverlay class and not in this constructor, is this why the text is not being drawn on the map? If so how do I add the text to the map?

Do the things drawn in the `draw()` method automatically get added as an overlay? Coz i think thats what is causing the problem here...
Any other way I can add text labels next to my overlay images?
Plz help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
MyLocationOverlay myTouchOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay ();
List<Overlay> list1 = myMapView.getOverlays();
list1.add(myTouchOverlay);



class MyLocationOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {


@Override
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView    mapView)  {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
            long when) {

        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        // Converts lat/lng-Point to OUR coordinates on the screen.
        Point myScreenCoords = new Point();

        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point, myScreenCoords);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        paint.setTextSize(20);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);


         canvas.drawText("Here I am...", myScreenCoords.x-10,myScreenCoords.y-48, paint);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: umm...I dont see any difference between this and what i did. Even i has my canvas.drawText in my draw method...wasnt working...

Comment: i am using the same thing as written in ur code...and it doesnt work...i am also using drawtext but nothing comes on the screen..

Comment: in drawText 2nd n 3rd parameter is position of x and y of screen and u have use 28632877,77219722 I think screen not found x =28632877 and y=77219722 . I am not sure.  Just replace with x=50 y=50 instead of your value..

Comment: ok...found it...but its at 50,50 _always_ . Its not getting attached to my map..its just stays at a particular point on my screen even if i move around...any fixes?

Comment: Point myScreenCoords = new Point(); mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point, myScreenCoords);
now change x=myScreenCoords.x

Comment: umm..its not able to identify the `point` in the code: map.getProjections().toPixels(**point**,myScreenCoords);

Comment: so..according to this code..where will it draw the text? Where is it detecting the myScreenCoords from? They havent been entered explicitly..

Comment: ok..i did what u told me to do..and this makes the text come in the center of the screen even if i am dragging around. Thats not what i want. I want to attach some text to the map at a particular geopoint. The text should stay at the specified geopoint...

Comment: This text is draw at point(GeoPoint)...So, first you have to define GeoPoint